# ID not getting from fired event

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, string

I'm adding an image button as an html element like a string in a gridview using JQuery. Grid view is populating correctly with all the value and this delete button. But when clicking on delete button, the ID passing to button click event is empty. I believe it's something to do with the string formation (may be quotes are misplaced) specially in the part **CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'**. Can someone help me to verify the html element string I created is correct?

```
//string which is added to grid view row for image button
var stringVal ='<asp:ImageButton ID="remove" runat="server" ImageUrl ="~/images/delete.gif" HeaderText="Image" OnCommand= "RemoveOneByOne_Click" CommandName="deleteOneByOne" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'/>';
```

```
//button click event where CommandArgument coming as empty
protected void RemoveOneByOne_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)

        {
            if (e.CommandName == "deleteOneByOne")

            {
                string ID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
             }
        }
```

Comment: How exactly does the HTML relate to your C# code? Are you missing a tag on your question?

Comment: Adding server control to GridView doesn't work this way. The JQuery executes on the client (browser). anything `runat="server"` should be done  by the server..

Comment: `<asp:ImageButton` is not client-side HTML.  It's server-side *markup* that the *server* renders into HTML.  jQuery doesn't know how to do this (as it's not ASP.net) so you just get the markup in your output.  Add `<asp.ImageButton...` to your page's source, then *view the rendered HTML* - it will likely create "real" HTML such as `<button><img></img></button>`